# Custom InputBox Not Recording Response

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have created a custom `InputBox` using `frmInputBox.ShowDialog` and using 2 buttons titled "OK" and 'Cancel", with them set to the `AcceptButton` & `CancelButton` respectively. This is simply so I can have the `InputBox` match the formatting of my main `Form`. However when I enter a value into the `TextBox` on `frmInputBox` the form doesn't disappear and my code gets hung up with the `InputBox` still open.

I tested my code using a custom `MessageBox` and with all the same options it works perfectly fine. The issue with the `InputBox` must have something to do with the `TextBox` not being recorded properly. But I don't see any options in the `TextBox` control to set it up as a `Dialog` option.

Here's sample code for my `MessageBox`:

```
frmMessageBox.lblMessageText.Text = "Would You Like To Clear The Event Log?"
frmMessageBox.ShowDialog()
If frmMessageBox.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK Then
    txtEventLog.Clear()
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Here's sample code for my `InputBox`:

```
frmInputBox.lblDialogText.Text = "Enter Number of times this program should be executed:"
frmInputBox.ShowDialog()
If frmInputBox.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK Then
    ProgramCounter = frmInputBox.txtDialogInput.Text
Else
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Is there something I'm missing that I need to do with the `InputBox` in order to get it to act the way I am expecting it to?

Comment: Are you saying that clicking one of the `Buttons` closes the dialogue if the `TextBox` is empty but not if it contains text?

Comment: By the way, don't call `ShowDialog` and then separately test the value of `DialogResult`.  Test the value returned by `ShowDialog`, i.e. `If frmMessageBox.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes if there is no text in the `TextBox` then the form closes and gives me a conversion from string to integer error. If there's anything in the `TextBox` then the InputBox just sits there doing nothing. However, If i put `frmInputBox.ShowDialog()` and then say `If frmMessageBox.showdialog() = DialogResult.Ok` then it'll show the `InputBox`, I'll then enter a number, hit cancel on the `InputBox`, then hit OK on the `MessageBox` and the program will continue running...What the F@%!??? Btw the `MessageBox` is just like the `InputBox` except for the `TextBox`

Comment: Oh jeez... Seeing the `MessageBox` work made me think something was wrong with my `InputBox` OK button...Well it turns out I never set the `DialogResult` of the OK `Button` to `DialogResult.OK`...fml. But since my `InputBox` Cancel button was set to `DialogResult.Cancel` it would work and open the `MessageBox`. Lol

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I've finally got my custom `MessageBox` and `InputBox` to work! That's awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For messagebox, I have answer before, and for inputbox, same as messagebox you need a module1:

```
Module Module1
    Public theResult As String

    Public Function myInputBox(ByVal promptText As String) As String
        InputBoxForm.lblPrompt.Text = promptText
        InputBoxForm.ShowDialog()
        myInputBox = theResult
    End Function
end Module
```

You need inputbox form:

```
Public Class InputBoxForm

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        theResult = txtInputResponse.Text
        Me.Close()
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        theResult = ""
        Me.Close()
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then you can call your input box like this:

```
    Dim theRslt as String = myInputBox("Enter Number of times this program should be executed:")
    MsgBox(theRslt)
```

Comment: This will not compile. Please STOP posting answers without testing them first.

Comment: Sorry, but I have tested it before, and have tested again today, and it run well on me without any error message, so I don't know, why it can't be compiled. In event btnTest_Click of form1 I put myTextResult.Text = myInputBox("Please Input Your String"), and after form inputbox have response, followed by btnok or btncancel, myTextResult textBox get as data from txtinputresponse textbox of InputBoxForm. I don't know, it is because of by not used variable or by myInputBox = MsgBoxResult.Cancel or others...

Comment: Have you turned on Option Strict? You need to have this on for all your coding in vb.net.

Comment: In VB6 you set a value equal to the name of a Function. In vb.net you use the Return keyword to return the value and execution to the calling code. You try to assign MsgBoxResult.Cancel to a string. MsgBoxResult.Cancel returns an Integer.